# Bluetooth doesn't seem to work with iPazzport dongle

Tags: bluetooth

I have a fresh install of Raspbian on my Pi 2.

Install was without problem, and I have it setup to boot to X11 at startup. I have used `apt-get` to get all the latest updates.

I do have an iPazzport KP-810-21B keyboard/trackpad Bluetooth which I would like to use with my Pi. Unfortunately after installing all the Bluetooth package:

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman
```

And rebooting still it doesn't work. When I launch the Bluetooth Manager app, the adapter/dongle is not listed.

Looking for more details, this is what I am getting:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0c40:8000 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un  802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

So looks like the `Device 011 ID 0c40:8000` is the dongle for my iPazzport.

And checking the "devices" in `/proc`:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0c40 Product=8000 Version=0111
N: Name="ELMCU 2.4GHz receiver"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:0C40:8000.000A/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 7 ff800000 7ff febeffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0c40 Product=8000 Version=0111
N: Name="ELMCU 2.4GHz receiver"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/0003:0C40:8000.000B/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3007f 0 0 0 0 483ffff 17aff32d bf544446 0 0 1f0001 130f93 8b17c000 677bfa d941dfed 9ed680 4400 0 10000002
B: REL=143
B: ABS=1 0
B: MSC=10
```

The output of `hciconfig -a` is not returning anything... and checking:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
```

shows the usual `[ok] bluetooth is running`... Not sure what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Bluetooth, it's RF. As ridiculous as it sounds, I was able to get mine to work simply by following the steps in the (badly translated) manual -- charge keyboard fully, turn on and press the FN and F1 let's simultaneously, THEN insert USB dongle. I was able to get mine to work on Raspbian Jessie, OpenELEC, and RetroPie this way, after just a few repetitions.

Comment: Thanks! I should have updated my questions a while back and yes it is RF not BT!